# unable to access mysql database with no password to git

Tags: mysql, shell

I am trying to access github database from the terminal and I am getting this error. Any suggestions? Below is the link for accessing the database.

[http://ghtorrent.org/mysql.html](http://gitlink)

```
  ssh -L 3306:web.ghtorrent.org:3306 ghtorrent@web.ghtorrent.org
  Enter passphrase for key '/Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa': 
  bind: Address already in use
  channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 3306
  Could not request local forwarding.
  PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

  on the other terminal 2
  mysql -u ght -h 127.0.0.1 ghtorrent
  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ght'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something (probably a local mysqld) on your local system is already listening on port 3306, so your port forward is not working, as `ssh` tries to explain in this series of error messages:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 3306
```

Use a different local port, and specify that port in your `mysql` client invocation. For example, to use port 33306:

```
ssh -L 33306:web.ghtorrent.org:3306 ghtorrent@web.ghtorrent.org
```

and

```
mysql -u ght -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33306 ghtorrent
```